how to save changes made in /ect/adduser.conf?

while overwriting the changes made in default home section ctrl+O i got a another prompt message with many options which i don't have any idea. can anyone help me with the further options that need to be selected? so i can save the changes made.

The prompt is simply to press enter if you wish to write out the changes to the already existing file. You may wish to make a copy of the original first before saving any changes, just to be certain so you can go back to the original if needs must.

@graham oh! you mean i don't have to choose any options in the below. just press enter and changes will be made... yeah now it makes sense for the cursor pointing for a name to ave the original file... thank you so much brother.

correct - you selected the ^O option to write out the already existing file you selected in the first place.

@graham - now when pressed enter i get permission denied! Am I not allowed to change/overwrite line in adduser.conf ?? or is there something i am missing here?

you didn't open the file with sudo perhaps sudo nano <filename> If the file is still open, highlight the text you changed, and reopen the file, copy/paste (or just redo the changes) and you should be able to save it out. The paste function in terminal is Ctrl+Shift+V

yes! you man on point...I'm an idiot! i didn't add sudo. Have made changes in lines and it works properly... once again thanks for the info.

More than welcome, Happens to us all from time to time. You usually get a red warning box at the bottom of the screen to indicate the file is unwritable.

This question is similar to: Using vi to edit a file in terminal. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@karel - In vi editor changes made in file reflects immediately after we use esc key follwed by :wq ... i didn't find the same flow while saving changes made in nano /etc/adduser.conf ... which while saving using ^O led to prompt which further had no instructions to complete the saving process ...

as a new beginner i found the interface not helping me further in the process ... where in which i had to again press enter to complete the save action ... which in my opinion wasn't user friendly cause i could have easily corrupted  the file and made a wrong choice without a proper guidance from the interface ... where i lost a lot of time ... a simple enter to save option in below could have made things easier referring to the above image.
